# How do I access the member `top` of a BIGNUM in OpenSSL 1.1.x?

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm currently trying to port an old C++ project over from OpenSSL 1.0.2 to OpenSSL 1.1.1. It's worth noting that this is not my code, but from an open source project, and I can't tell exactly what this part is supposed to do.
One file uses this piece of code (simplified for this post):

```
BIGNUM *d; //Assume this is a valid, populated BIGNUM
int x = d->top;
```

Unfortunately, the BIGNUM structure is now opaque in OpenSSL 1.1.x, meaning its member, `top`, cannot be directly accessed anymore.
With that said, I have a few questions:

1. Is there a drop-in replacement I can use to access `top`?
2. What does `top` represent? (IIRC it holds the MSB of the bignum, but I can't find any place to confirm that)
3. Otherwise, is there a way I can avoid using `top` at all?

The code in question is available [here](https://github.com/lwakefield/libgpucrypto/blob/master/rsa_cuda.cu), line `196` is where the first instance of `d->top` can be found.
The entire project is located [in this repository](https://github.com/lwakefield/libgpucrypto/).

Comment: "*Otherwise, is there a way I can avoid using `top` at all?*" - hard to  answer that without seeing how the code is using the `top` to begin with.

Comment: Yes I am aware, which is is why I mentioned that I can provide the code. I'll edit the post to be more clear about that EDIT: Actually I'll just link the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full example you linked, copies out the bits from a `BIGNUM` (for the RSA d exponent) into a different structure. It does not only access `d->top` (which is the number of used chunks), but also `d->d` (the pointer to the actual chunks) as the source of the `memcpy` in the next line.

The canonical way to copy out the bits of a `BIGNUM` is [bn2bin](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/BN_bn2bin.html).

As for your specific questions:

1. Generally speaking, no, as its semantics refer to the internal representation. However, you can easily compute the *required* size from the `BIGNUM`s number of bits, which you already have access to.
2. [The number of chunks used to store the `BIGNUM`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/a935791d54078f43209ffbc1886ac5e68772ce34/crypto/bn/bn_local.h#L228)
3. By exporting the function into an appropriately sized target buffer using an [export function](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/BN_bn2bin.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Am I correct in assuming each chunk is the same size as a `BN_ULONG`? Meaning `d->top*sizeof(BN_ULONG)` at line `197` can simply be replaced by `BN_num_bytes(d)`?

Lastly, the docs for `BN_bn2bin` states `to` `must point to BN_num_bytes(a) bytes of memory.`, does this mean I need to do something special to allocate that memory to `to`?